# How to write an exception where if the constraint exists i just skip over the ones that exist and move on with the code?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I am trying to insert some rows into respondent but the table has an integrity constraint where i can only insert cycle_samples that aren't yet in the respondent. I don't want to delete these records from the table as there are multiple parents / childs that are dependent on these entries. How can I write an exception to handle this type of error? I did some research and couldn't really find an exception handler for this type of situation... my code is below:

```
 create or replace Procedure RESPONDENT IS
 CURSOR c1 is 
     select e.entity_id, scp.create_dt, scp.cycle_sample_id
     from entity e
     join  entity_survey es on e.entity_id = es.entity_id
     join cycle sc on es.cycle_id = sc.cycle_id
     join cycle_sample scp on sc.cycle_id = scp.cycle_id
    join cycle_period scp on sc.cycle_id = scp.cycle_id
    where e.entity_id = 0;
 l_var c1%ROWTYPE;
    BEGIN
          OPEN c1;
    LOOP
          FETCH c1 into l_var;
          EXIT when c1%NOTFOUND;
           insert into respondent (cycle_sample_id, entity_id, create_dt, create_user_id, modify_dt, modify_user_id, effective_dt, inactive_Dt, exclude_from_weighting)
           values (l_var.cycle_sample_id, l_var.entity_id, sysdate, '1', null, null, null, null, 'N');
END LOOP;
    EXCEPTION
       **WHEN INTEGRITY CONSTRAINT VIOLATED / ERROR?**
close c1;
 END RESPONDENT;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need an exception handler for this specific example (avoiding unique constraint violations during insert), as there is a hint for it:

```
create or replace procedure respondent
as
begin
    for r in (
        select e.entity_id, scp.create_dt, scp.cycle_sample_id
        from   entity e
               join entity_survey es
                    on  e.entity_id = es.entity_id
               join cycle sc
                    on  es.cycle_id = sc.cycle_id
               join cycle_sample scp
                    on  sc.cycle_id = scp.cycle_id
               join cycle_period scp
                    on  sc.cycle_id = scp.cycle_id
        where  e.entity_id = 0
    )
    loop
        insert /*+ ignore_row_on_dupkey_index(respondent(cycle_sample_id,entity_id) ) */
        into respondent
            ( cycle_sample_id
            , entity_id
            , create_dt
            , create_user_id
            , exclude_from_weighting )
        values
            ( l_var.cycle_sample_id
            , l_var.entity_id
            , sysdate
            , '1'
            , 'N' );
    end loop;
end respondent;
```

(I don't know what the unique constraint is on your table so you may need to adjust the column list in the hint to avoid `ORA-38913: Index specified in the index hint is invalid`.)

However if this is all the procedure does, why not just

```
create or replace procedure respondent
as
begin
    insert /*+ ignore_row_on_dupkey_index(respondent(cycle_sample_id,entity_id) ) */
    into respondent
        ( cycle_sample_id
        , entity_id
        , create_dt
        , create_user_id
        , exclude_from_weighting )
    select e.entity_id, scp.create_dt, scp.cycle_sample_id
    from   entity e
           join entity_survey es
                on  e.entity_id = es.entity_id
           join cycle sc
                on  es.cycle_id = sc.cycle_id
           join cycle_sample scp
                on  sc.cycle_id = scp.cycle_id
           join cycle_period scp
                on  sc.cycle_id = scp.cycle_id
    where  e.entity_id = 0
end respondent;
```

By the way, you can't give a table and a procedure the same name within the same schema.

Answer (score 1):

Put the exception handler *inside* the loop and `CONTINUE` the loop when there is a constraint violation.

To do that, you could structure your program like this:

```
create or replace Procedure RESPONDENT IS
 CURSOR c1 is ...
 l_var c1%ROWTYPE;
    BEGIN
          OPEN c1;
    <<my_loop>>
    LOOP
      BEGIN
          FETCH c1 into l_var;
          EXIT when c1%NOTFOUND;
           insert into respondent ...
      EXCEPTION
        WHEN ??? /* constraint violated */ THEN
          -- log as appropriate
          CONTINUE my_loop;
       END;
    END LOOP;
    close c1;
 END RESPONDENT;
```

Comment: thanks Matthew. do you know what the syntax for the handling constraint violation may be? I couldn't find it anywhere

Comment: It depends on the type of constraint.  If you have no exception handlers at all, what ORA error do you get?

Comment: I did some further digging is it: DUP_VAL_ON_INDEX?

Comment: Then should just be "WHEN dup_val_on_index"